# moment format verbose date as date object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs, materialize

I used materialize datepicker to pick a date in french format. Now I need this date formatted back to a date object so I can use it in my api. Here's how I try to convert the date back to a normal format:

```
moment("dimanche 30 juillet 2017","dddd D MMMM YYYY").locale('fr').toDate();
```

But I receive `Invalid Date`. Is there a way to convert this date back using **moment**? Or can I somehow hook to **materialize** component to retrieve a normal date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the fr locale before attempting to parse french day/monthnames.

```
moment.locale('fr');
moment("dimanche 30 juillet 2017","dddd D MMMM YYYY").toDate();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can parse your input string passing locale parameter, see [`moment(String, String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) docs:

> As of version **2.0.0**, a locale key can be passed as the third parameter to `moment()` and `moment.utc()`.

Here a working sample:

```js
var m = moment("dimanche 30 juillet 2017", "dddd D MMMM YYYY", 'fr');
console.log(m.toDate());
console.log(m.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

For further info see [Changing locale globally](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/) and [Changing locales locally](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/).